# Why does Helmet block access to YouTube videos in my Express app, which uses embedded YouTube player?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, embedded-resource, helmet.js

I have written an Express app, where users can post YouTube videos. YouTube videos are embedded with iframe elements in the relevant view, with YouTube embedded player. Before I tried to deploy the app, I added Helmet, with its recommended setup, which is good for most applications. The YouTube videos were not visible after this, even the player was not visible. This functionality was completely broken, the app just ignored the YouTube player without any error message. The code can be found with the deployed working version at [members-only](https://github.com/AlexErdei73/members-only). The app.js file is pretty long, so please see it on GitHub. So the app got broken when I imported Helmet and added the following line:
`app.use(helmet())`

I found a solution, with some setup on Helmet and adding an extra, small middleware. So the following code made the YouTube player work again:

```
app.use(
    helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            directives: {
                "frame-ancestors": ["'self'", "https://www.youtube.com/"],
                frameSrc: ["'self'", "https://www.youtube.com/"],
                childSrc: ["'self'", "https://www.youtube.com/"],
            },
        },
        referrerPolicy: false,
        originAgentCluster: false,
    })
);

//Without this middleware embedded youtube video is not working with helmet
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "cross-origin");
    next();
});
```

My problem is that I have no idea, why the above code is working. What have I done? Can anybody explain why referrerPolicy and originAgentCluster needed to be disabled and what the middleware does? I have some fuzzy ideas about the contentSecurityPolicy settings with the docs, but it leads me to content, that I cannot understand yet. Sorry, I am quite a newbie with web security. I hope there must be someone, who knows exactly what's going on and can explain it in plain English. Thank you

Comment: It's standard security in most modern browsers. By adding a 'whitelist' you could bypass the security filter for the selected URLs.

Comment: Thank you for giving me an answer, which is at least in plain English. Unfortunately, it does not add too much to my understanding. Maybe just the question is wrong because it cannot be explained in plain English better. I perhaps need to learn more about the complex mechanism, by which the browser tries to protect the user against malicious attacks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, helmet blocked my youtube iframes too but i just have finally found the solution:

```
app.use(helmet({
        crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: false,
        crossOriginOpenerPolicy: true
    })
    );
```

make sure crossOriginEmbedderPolicy is set to false and crossOriginOpenerPolicy is set to true, works for me

Comment: It looks much simpler than the solution, which I found. That is great. Do you know why it is working? Is there any resource, which explains these things in detail in a readable format?

Comment: I tried your version in my app and it is not working there.